# Correctly proxy nginx to django app with a subpath

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, uwsgi

I've been unable to fix this for almost a week now and would really appreciate some help. I feel like theres something I dont really understand and Im becoming increasingly frustrated because I cant seem to find a clear answer on this problem anywhere.

Lets say I want to run a django app with uwsgi or gunicorn and have it be accessible via a subpath like for example : **"www.mysite.com/app1"**

I create a nginx proxy_pass like this:

```
location /app1/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

Now. This far it works fine and I get redirected to the Django **"/"** page. If however I try to access **"www.mysite.com/app1/admin"** for example, I will be redirected to **"www.mysite.com/admin"**, which is wrong. If I look at the nginx logs, I can see that there is a **301** Redirect for **"www.mysite.com/app1/admin"** and then obviously a **404** Not Found for **"www.mysite.com/admin"**.

I understand the problem is obviously that somehow Django or Uwsgi/Gunicorn need to know about the subpath I defined in Nginx. But I really cant find to seem a conlcusive answer of what the correct way of doing this is.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show full nginx conf.

Comment: You need to add the prefix to your urls.py (all of them, maybe use one `include` for that) because that's how browsers work, paths are always relative to the domain. So when Django reverses a url, it needs to append this /app1/

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes I thought about that. I dont feel like this is a clean solution though.

Comment: There's no other way, nginx cannot solve this. Your urls in your entire site must start with /app1/. It's just one line in urls.py (and you could fetch the prefix from your settings, if you want to differentiate between development and production).